# Google Plus Authentication - Ajax token

Tags: php, google-plus

I'm playing around with the Google Plus API.  I want to create a basic application that stores the users details into my database using the server-side process:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

I'm currently up to Step 6.  My button appears on the page, and I can send the `code` (id) over to the server using ajax.  Something like:

```
var dataString = 'auth= ' +authResult['code'];

// Send the code to the server
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'storeToken',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: dataString,
    processData: false,
    statusCode: {
        200: function(result){
            $('#test').html(result);
                if (result['profile'] && result['people']){
                    $('#test').html('Hello ' + result['profile']['displayName'] + '. You successfully made a server side call to people.get and people.list');
                } else {
                    $('#test').html('Failed to make a server-side call. Check your configuration and console.');
                }
        }

    },
});
```

Now in the documents, it says that I should be converting the `code` to  access_token and refresh_token - however this is the part I can't seem to do...

Where my ajax posts to, I can use $code which is successfully passed from my script above. I've tried:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->authenticate($code);
```

But from here, I do not know what to do.  The docs mention in the response it can use: `result['profile']['displayName']` but, I don't have a clue how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The next thing you need to do is extract the access token. This will allow you to begin making API calls on behalf of the authenticated user.

`$token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());`

You'll also want to verify the token. To see the full example, check Step 8 at https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#using_one-time-code_flow.